# Non-zero mean and finite-variance Gaussian Squared R.V has Non-central Chi squared distribution, but how?

Tags: chi-squared-distribution, non-central

If $$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$$

then $$X^2 \sim \frac{e^{-\frac{\left(\mu +\sqrt{x}\right)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \left(e^{\frac{2 \mu  \sqrt{x}}{\sigma ^2}}+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma  \sqrt{x}} \hspace{3 mm}, \hspace{3 mm} x>0$$

If $X^2$ has been known as non-central chi square distribution ($\mathcal{X^2(1,\lambda)}$) then how to calculate the non-centrality parameter in context of above distribution of $X^2$, so that both the distributions become equal? Any help please.

Comment: You are mistaken in your premises: $X^2$ does *not* have a $\chi^2(1,\lambda)$ distribution.  It is $\sigma^2$ times such a distribution.  By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Background), the noncentrality parameter of that distribution is $\lambda=(\mu/\sigma)^2$.

Comment: I mean a non-central chi square distribution, which has two parameters: degree of freedom and non-central parameter.

Comment: Yes, it is clear that's what you mean--but you are wrong to suppose that the $X^2$ you exhibit here has such a non-central $\chi^2$ distribution.  *It does not.*  After you rescale it by $1/\sigma$, it will have that distribution, whose PDF is given by a modified Bessel function $I_{-1/2}$. This fact is readily checked after you recognize that $I_{-1/2}(z) = \sqrt{1/(2\pi z)}\left(\exp(z)+\exp(-z)\right)$.

Comment: @whuber Nice description. So $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ doesn't have a non central Chi-Square distribution. so does the distribution of $X^2$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ has any particular name?

Comment: A multiple of a distribution occurs so often and is so simply related to the distribution itself that it need not have any special name.  For that reason, for example, the square of a Normal$(0,\sigma)$ distribution has no special name, either: it's just $\sigma^2$ times a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution.

Comment: I heard many people still call it non-central chi square, though it is basically incorrect to call so. So, is it a misnomer or people are incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17843/discussion-between-whuber-and-kaka).

Comment: What is the proof of the given result please?

Answer (score 6):

As already answered by whuber in above comments:

If $$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma),$$ and $$Y \sim \chi^2 \Big(k=1,\lambda=\Big(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\Big)^2 \Big),$$

then  $$X^2\stackrel{d}{=}\sigma^2 Y.$$

In words, if X is normal random variable with non-zero mean and variance and Y is non-central chi squared random variable with one degree of freedom and non-central parameter $\lambda=(\frac{\mu}{\sigma})^2$, then $X^2$ is equal in distribution to $\sigma^2$Y.

Moreover, a scaled non-central chi square variable doesn't have the non-central chi squared distribution.

It should be $X^2$ in the conclusion.